# Is JavaScript and rendering as fast in IE9 as compared to IE9 in IE7 mode?

Tags: performance, javascript, internet-explorer-9

A program I use creates ActiveX browsers to render webpages and I understand this uses the installed Internet Explorer browser instead of a copy of it's core. So the program must be forcing IE7 compatibility mode because the useragent returns MSIE7 when IE8 or IE9 are installed.

So would it still be as fast for JavaScript, using the GPU, rendering big tables and overall speed?

Comment: not having used IE9 yet.. I am surprised they still have IE7 mode built into it.. geez.. let IE6/7 die already.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a true test, I ran IE9's [Psychedelic Browser test](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/PsychedelicBrowsing/Default.html) and [V8 Benchmark suite](http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/data/benchmarks/v6/run.html) in both normal and compatibility view.

---

Normal view

[image: Psychedelic normal]

[image: V8 Normal]

---

Compatibility view

[image: Psychedelic compatibility]

V8 benchmarks:

[image: V8 compatibility]

There isn't much of a difference between both, so I guess it's fair to say that it should be as fast & will definitely use the GPU under IE7 mode